# How to install PySP for Pyomo 6.5?

Tags: pyomo

I have to solve a stochastic programming problem and I would like to use PySP.
The thing is that I want to install it, because from version 6.0 it is distributed as an independent package, but I don't know how to do it. I have tried the following command

```
pip install pysp
```

And it seems that it installs, but when I try to invoke the rapper
with the command

```
import pyomo.pysp.util.rapper as rapper
```

I get an error message saying that the pysp.util module does not exist.

How can I fix it? Am I installing it right?

Answer (score 0):

PySP is no longer being actively developed or maintained. The PySP developers have reimplemented much of the functionality from PySP in a new scalable framework called mpi-sppy. Documentation can be found here: https://mpi-sppy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I recommend using mpi-sppy instead of PySP if you're using a recent version of Pyomo like 6.5.0.

Comment: Hi, @Bethany Nicholson.  I know that the mpi-sppy package exists, on the Pyomo website it says https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modeling_extensions/stochastic_programming.html , in fact I have it installed. However, the website also says that you can use the PySP package, but you need to install it from version 6.0 onwards, as I said in my question.

Comment: I just wanted to compare one with the other and check which one was easier to use, because as it also says on the web, mpi-sppy, https://mpi-sppy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html users are seen as developers, not end users, and I thought that with the programming knowledge I have, it would be easier to use PySP.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question seemed inappropriate, but as I said, I was simply curious to compare one package with another.

Comment: I think it's a valid question my point is that PySP is not being maintained so there is no guarantee that it works with more recent versions of Pyomo like 6.5.0. If you're fine with doing a comparison with older versions of Pyomo and mpi-sppy, you could revert to Pyomo 6.0 which I believe is the last time any of the developers verified that PySP was supported.